# How to make my bulk uploader code more efficient?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, upload, bulk-load

I wrote a python script to bulk upload files from a folder into postgresql. While the script works, I do not think it's super efficient. Can anyone tell me how to improve it?

It takes a very long time for the files to actually be uploaded.

Spacing/indentation is slightly off in posting, this is not an issue in actual script.

---

def addFilesToDatabase(directory):

```
uploadedFiles = []
errorFiles = []

rows_to_chunk_by = 1000

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    try:
        filename_used = filename.upper()

        if filename_used.endswith(".CSV"):
            file_directory = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            tableName = filename_used.replace('.CSV','')
            df = pd.read_csv(file_directory, header=0, nrows = 1)
            columns = df.columns
            while 1==1:
                for skiprows in range(100000000):
                    if(skiprows == 0):
                        df = pd.read_csv(file_directory, header=0, nrows = rows_to_chunk_by, skiprows = skiprows*rows_to_chunk_by)
                        df.to_sql(name=tableName, con=engine, if_exists='append', schema=None, index=False)
                    else:
                        df = pd.read_csv(file_directory, header=None, nrows = rows_to_chunk_by, skiprows = skiprows*rows_to_chunk_by)
                        df.columns = columns
                        df.to_sql(name=tableName, con=engine, if_exists='append', schema=None, index=False)
                        if(len(df)<rows_to_chunk_by):
                            break
                uploadedFiles.append(filename)
                break
   except Exception as e:
        if str(e) == "No columns to parse from file":
            uploadedFiles.append(filename)
        elif str(e)[0:16] == "Length mismatch:":
            uploadedFiles.append(filename)
        else:
            errorFiles.append(filename)
            print('Error with ' + filename)
            print(e)
            continue
```

Comment: Asking for "better" options is generally too broad question. May be suitable for http://CodeReview.stackexchange.com if asking to make working code generically better.

Comment: What is the point of "skiprows"?

Comment: What class is "pd"?